# List of all existing WinApi Functions

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, windows-10, windows-7

Is there a list of existing winapi functions? [This](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8614193) paper claims it analyzed around 22000 winapi functions. Are those functions listed on a windows machine somewhere? Or are there websites that list those?

When following @IInspectable's approach I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [A]re there websites that list those [winapi functions]?

Possibly. If there are, they probably suck. Either way, if that is your question, it would be [off-topic](/help/on-topic) around here.

> Are those [winapi] functions listed on a windows machine somewhere?

No. There's no practical reason to have that listing. Applications know which APIs they need and either the OS loader will resolve those dependencies (for compile-time dynamic linking), or the runtime dynamic linking will report its outcome to the calling application.

Neither one requires a listing of all available APIs they aren't interested in calling anyway. If your application doesn't plan to call [TABTHETEXTOUTFORWIMPS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031015-00/?p=42163), it likely has no interest in knowing, where `TABTHETEXTOUTFORWIMPS` actually lives.

---

The available API calls are published by way of the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/). It includes both the function signatures, required by your compiler, as well as the information on where to find the functions' implementations, which the linker is mightily interested in.

---

It's the Windows SDK that has the information you appear to be interested in<sup>1</sup>.

The [Win32 Metadata](https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata) project collects metadata by scanning the Windows SDK header files, and makes it available as a machine-readable assembly. The results are [published](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Win32Metadata/) to the NuGet gallery.

The assembly can be opened with any tool that understands ECMA-335 metadata (like Visual Studio's Object Browser or [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)). If neither of those tools meet your immediate needs, you can parse the data yourself and derive arbitrary information. The binary file format is [documented](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) (*"Partition II: Metadata Definition and Semantics"* has all the information you'd need to parse out that information).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Apparently, the cardinality of the the Windows API surface. Not that I'd challenge the paper's authors' intentions, though I'd probably miss out on reading a paper that has* "Deep Learning" *in its title, even if my time weren't resource-constrained. With a pretty high probability it's just complete garbage.*

Comment: I downloaded the .nupkg but how can I open it in Visual Studios?

Comment: Extract the *Windows.Win32.winmd* file from the *nupkg* archive. Open the *Object Browser* (Ctrl+Alt+J) and add the .winmd file using the *Edit Custom Component Set* option, either from the *Browse* option or the *...* shortcut.

Comment: I get the error "The chosen component could not be searched" roughly translated to english.

Comment: Which operation did fail?

Comment: Adding the .winmd to the component set failed.

Comment: I changed the language package and the error message is "The selected component could not be browsed"

Comment: Did you extract the .winmd file or did you try to add the .nupkg file?

Comment: I used 7zip to extract the .winmd file as well as everything else in the .nupkg. Then I opened the Object Browser and added the .winmd file. Then the error pops up. I will add a screenshot to the opening question, for better illustration.

Comment: According to [win32metadata overview](https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata/tree/v10.2.84-preview#overview), if you'd like to browse the metadata to see what they are emitting, download the **NuGet** package and load the included *winmd* file in **ILSpy**.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest release (10.2.84-preview), extracted the *Windows.Win32.winmd* file and added it to the *Object Browser* in Visual Studio. After opening the *Edit Custom Component Set* dialog, move to the *Browse* tab, and add the file.